# if the even float number ( fraction number) is modulus by 2 then it does not give '0' as result! in C++

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
        {
            double x;
            cin>> x;
            cout<< fmod(x,2.00);
         }
```

If i give the input number as 2.4 ,it gives an output:0.4. How can i get the output 0.00?

Comment: I don't understand why you think it should be 0.

Comment: That's exactly what it's supposed to do. the remainder of x / 2.0 when x = 2.4 is 0.4. Maybe you wanted floor(x / 2.0)? Or maybe you wanted (int)x % 2?

Comment: Parity (even vs. odd) applies only to integers, not numbers with fractional parts.

Comment: This is normal. see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod

Answer (score 2):

Only integers can be even or odd, a real number like 2.4 is neither odd nor even. If you want to test whether the integer part of a floating point number is even or odd, you can cast it to an integer type (which will truncate the fractional part) and use `%`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double x;
    cin >> x; // you should check that cin is good!
    cout << (static_cast<int>(x) % 2) << endl;
}
```

Some things that you should try, check and handle appropriately:

- negative numbers
- huuuuuge numbers
- non-numbers